# How to use react-jsonschema-form in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

i have an issue with building forms in react with json. I've installed react-jsonschema-form but I just can't get it to work. I have the package installed locally, I am using TypeScript and I'm using nx/nrwl. This is what I've tried.

```
import React from 'react';
import './form.scss';

const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
    type: "string"
};

/* eslint-disable-next-line */
export interface FormProps {
    json: any;
}


export const FormComponent = (props: FormProps) => {
        return (
            <>
                <Form schema={schema}/>
            </>
        );
    }
;

export default FormComponent;
```

The question is where do i get the JSONSchemaForm variable from?

For example, this little snippet works like a charm
https://codepen.io/krcaltomas99/pen/abvaJdb

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `JSONSchemaForm` is the name of the export that is loaded into your web app if you use the [CDN script import method](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation).

Since you said you installed the package, you can justuse the import syntax (i.e. `import Form from "@rjsf/core";`) and let your bundler take care handling the library dependency rather than modify your `index.html` to include the CDN script.

Answer (score 0):

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62036520/6243352) is correct in pointing out that the CDN script has somewhat different workflow, but I was confused because `import Form from "@rjsf/core";` didn't work for me on [`react-jsonschema-form`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsonschema-form) 1.7.0:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@rjsf/core'
```

It turns out there are two different packages. The older package (last updated in 2019 at the time of writing) `react-jsonschema-form` worked for me with the following boilerplate:

```js
import JSONSchemaForm from "react-jsonschema-form"; // 1.7.0
import React from "react"; // 17.0.2

const formSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: {
      name: "Name",
      type: "string",
      pattern: "^[a-zA-Z]+$",
      minLength: 10,
      maxLength: 50,
    },
  },
  required: ["name"],
};

const App = () => (
  <JSONSchemaForm
    onSubmit={f => console.log(f)}
    schema={formSchema}
  />
);

export default App;
```

And here's a complete example of the newer package, [`@rjsf/core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rjsf/core) 4.2.2:

```js
import Form from "@rjsf/core"; // 4.2.2
import React from "react"; // 17.0.2

const formSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: {
      name: "Name",
      type: "string",
      pattern: "^[a-zA-Z]+$",
      minLength: 10,
      maxLength: 50,
    },
  },
  required: ["name"],
};

const App = () => (
  <Form
     onSubmit={f => console.log(f)}
     schema={formSchema}
  />
);

export default App;
```

For completeness, here's a CDN version as a stack snippet:

```js
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
// or const {default: Form} = JSONSchemaForm;

const schema = {
  title: "Todo",
  type: "object",
  required: ["title"],
  properties: {
    title: {type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task"},
    done: {type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false}
  }
};

const log = (type) => console.log.bind(console, type);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(
    <Form schema={schema}
        onChange={log("changed")}
        onSubmit={log("submitted")}
        onError={log("errors")} />
  );
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@rjsf/core@4.2.3/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```